# Sorting by post views count doesnt work. Plugin: "Post Views Counter" - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Im making news blog and I need to display daily posts.

**How doest daily posts work in my blog?** : Im picking all posts for this day and sorting them by views count.

There is the problem: I can't sort by views count with [Post Views Counter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) plugin. It doesnt returning any posts on WP_Query.

My tryings:

```
function DisplayDailyNews(){
    $yesterday = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("yesterday"));
    $yesterdayarray = date_parse($yesterday);

    $dailyGridPostQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        "post_type"             => "post",
        "post_status "          => "publish",
        "posts_per_page"        => 3,
        "day"                   => $yesterdayarray["day"],
        "meta_key"              => "post_views_count",
        "orderby"               => "meta_value_num",
        "order"                 => "DESC"
    ));

    if ($dailyGridPostQuery->have_posts()){
        while ($dailyGridPostQuery->have_posts()){
            $dailyGridPostQuery->the_post(); 
            //Displaying post item here...
        } 
    }
}
```

I tried googling a solution but none of them worked for me.

---

FAQ1: Yes, I have posts for this day.

Comment: I think you're using day incorrectly https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

Comment: @Howard E i doesnt matter now. I checked by removing "day" field, that's not the problem.

Comment: Does `post_views_count` exist?

Comment: @Howard E Im using plugin. It should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin dont use custom field post_views_count for save post_count
Its create additional table

> $wpdb->prefix . "post_views

To order posts by post_views use

> "orderby"               => "post_views",

try this code

```
$dailyGridPostQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type"             => "post",
    "post_status "          => "publish",
    "posts_per_page"        => 3,
    "year"                  => $yesterdayarray["year"],
    "monthnum"              => $yesterdayarray["month"],
    "day"                   => $yesterdayarray["day"],
    "orderby"               => "post_views",
    "order"                 => "DESC"
));
```

P.S.
post_views need to be > 0